# Horizontal menu with a colored bar

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a page header with a menu just like the following image.

[image: Page header]

I'm creating the navigation so each link area (blue (rectangle?)) is a `<li>`. But I'm getting the items stacked vertically.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8kLfxj5/).

```
<header>
<div id="area-logo">
    <div class="header-ribbon"></div>
    <div class="container bg-white"></div>
</div>
<nav id="main-menu">
    <ul>
        <li id="link-a-link">
            <div class="header-ribbon"></div>
            <div class="container bg-white"> <a href="#">link a</a>

            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="link-b-link">
            <div class="header-ribbon"></div>
            <div class="container bg-white"> <a href="#">link b</a>

            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="link-c-link">
            <div class="header-ribbon"></div>
            <div class="container bg-white"> <a href="#">link c</a>

            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="link-d-link">
            <div class="header-ribbon"></div>
            <div class="container bg-white"> <a href="#">link d</a>

            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="link-e-link">
            <div class="header-ribbon"></div>
            <div class="container bg-white"> <a href="#">link e</a>

            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="link-f-link">
            <div class="header-ribbon"></div>
            <div class="container bg-white"> <a href="#">link f</a>

            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```
    header {
    background-color: #787aad;
    height: 126px;
}

header .header-ribbon {
    height: 6px;
}

header .bg-white {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#area-logo {
    float: left;
}

#main-menu ul {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
}

#main-menu ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

I need the colored bar over each link and over the logo area to have the same size of link area, so if I place a larger text, it will have its width increased too.

How can I do this?

[image: Expected result]

### UPDATE

Actually, the updated code on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n8kLfxj5/4/embedded/result/) does solve my problem. However this lead me to find a rendering bug on the new Microsoft Edge browser, as it is adding 1px to the `<li>` border-top.

[image: Result on MS Edge]

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveria Once again, if you found any answers helpful, please upvote and mark as accepted to close this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `display: inline;` to a `display: inline-block;` for the `li`s. Of course, you'll need to change more CSS to get the elements to look more like the picture, but that's the gist of what you were asking for.

To get the colored bar over each link, I added a `border-top: 6px solid #787aad;` to each `li`. I think that's what you wanted the `.header-ribbon` to do, but I set the style to `display: none;` to remove the gap. If you want to, you could re-show the `.header-ribbon`s, and add a style to them `background-color: #787aad;` to achieve the same effect of adding the `border-top` to each `li`.

```css
header {
  background-color: #444444;
  height: 126px;
}
header .header-ribbon {
  height: 6px;
  display: none;
}
header .bg-white {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#area-logo {
  float: left;
}
#main-menu ul {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
}
#main-menu ul li {
  border-top: 6px solid #787aad;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="area-logo">
    <div class="header-ribbon"></div>
    <div class="container bg-white"></div>
  </div>
  <nav id="main-menu">
    <ul>
      <li id="link-a-link">
        <div class="header-ribbon"></div>
        <div class="container bg-white"> <a href="#">link a</a>

        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="link-b-link">
        <div class="header-ribbon"></div>
        <div class="container bg-white"> <a href="#">link b</a>

        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="link-c-link">
        <div class="header-ribbon"></div>
        <div class="container bg-white"> <a href="#">link c</a>

        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="link-d-link">
        <div class="header-ribbon"></div>
        <div class="container bg-white"> <a href="#">link d</a>

        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="link-e-link">
        <div class="header-ribbon"></div>
        <div class="container bg-white"> <a href="#">link e</a>

        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="link-f-link">
        <div class="header-ribbon"></div>
        <div class="container bg-white"> <a href="#">link f</a>

        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

**EDIT #1:** As for expanding the logo element, you might go with adding `width: 50%;` to the `#area-logo` and `#main-menu` elements. You also might need to add `display: block;` to them.

Comment: @juliano-nunes-silva-olivei If you found my solution helpful, please upvote and mark as accepted so that this question may be closed.

Comment: Tried to change my code to use just the border-top instead of the div, but even with the sabe 6px height, the <li> border is larger than the <div>. http://jsfiddle.net/n8kLfxj5/1/

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira I'm not sure I get you. Can you post an image/jsFiddle for what you want it to **look** like?

Comment: fond42518, I added it to the end of my question. And here's the latest version of the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8kLfxj5/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Attached is the CSS you should use for getting things to align properly. I'm opposed to using `display: inline-block` because you should be using a float in this case.

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vrc4qhbn/2/

```
header {
    position: relative;
    }
    header *,
    header *:before,
    header *:after {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
        box-sizing:         border-box;
        }

    #area-logo {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 150px; /* Whatever youre value should be here */
        }
    #main-menu {
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 165px; /* Width of your logo plus spacing */
        }
        #main-menu > ul {
            float: right; /* Have navigation to the right */
            }
            #main-menu > ul > li {
                display: block; /* Make a block element */
                float: left; /* Each navigation item from the left */
                }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the only thing I need to change in my code? Tried it on jsFiddle and it didn't work as expected.

Comment: I added a JSFiddle for you. More refined CSS can be added, but you should see from the fiddle I added that this works.

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle to make it look a little cleaner: http://jsfiddle.net/vrc4qhbn/2/

Comment: And there are several ways to approach adding the ribbon to the top. The solution by fond42518 works, or you can do what I did by adding a color class to your existing HTML then modifying in the CSS. For that, fond42518 approach would be better because it assumes the removal of additional HTML. The lighter the better.

Comment: I actually kind of like what @ScriptsConnect did, since it may be better for sizing and cross-browser compatibility. However, as for rendering efficiency my solution might be better. It just depends on the usage. For just a few menubar items, your solution works fine, but if you're adding hundreds of these, a lightweight solution might be better. My solution may fail on mobile IE, Opera, and Blackberry, as well as Opera Mini.

Comment: The solution I made does take responsive design into consideration, but it doesnt have a mobile nav implementation. For that I suggest using custom jQuery (would be easiest). What you do is create a clone of your navigation, add an additional class to the clone, such as `mobilenav` to the clone parent, & then append your mobile nav to wherever you want it placed. Then, you add ur media queries to hide ur desktop nav & show your mobile nav at incremental positions, as in... `@media screen and (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 700px) { .desktopnav { display: none; } .mobilenav{ display: block; } }`

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS with this code:

```
#main-menu ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
```